# convert react function to class

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I've been struggling to convert this functional component to a class.
I used the npm-breadcrumbs-hoc plugin. It works perfectly just need to 
convert it to something like this format:

class Breadcrumb extends React.Component {
   ...
}

Can someone explain to me to me how to do this?
below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import WithBreadcrumbs from 'react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc';
import './Breadcrumb.css';

const merchantBreadcrumb = ({ match }) =>
    <span>{match.params.merchantName}</span>;


const routes = [
    { path: '/merchant/:merchantName', breadcrumb: merchantBreadcrumb },
];

const breadcrumb = ({ breadcrumbs }) => (
    <div className="breadcrumbComponent">
        {breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, index) => (
            <span key={breadcrumb.key}>
                <NavLink
                    className = 'highlight'
                    to = {breadcrumb.props.match.url}
                >
                    {breadcrumb}
                </NavLink>

                {(index < breadcrumbs.length - 1) && <i> > </i>}
            </span>
        ))}
    </div>
);

export default WithBreadcrumbs(routes)(breadcrumb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `({breadCrumbs})` is a destructured from `props`.

Your `breadCrumbs` is a handler to an anonymous function, which returns a component wrapped in `<div className="breadcrumbComponent">`.

So you need to *return* it in `render()` function.

```
  class BreadCrumb extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const {breadcrumbs} = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="breadcrumbComponent">
            {breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, index) => (
                <span key={breadcrumb.key}>
                    <NavLink
                        className = 'highlight'
                        to = {breadcrumb.props.match.url}
                    >
                        {breadcrumb}
                    </NavLink>

                    {(index < breadcrumbs.length - 1) && <i> > </i>}
                </span>
            ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

*I honestly don't see the benefit in this case since you aren't using any states.
Class components are useful if you need React lifecycle methods (such as `compoenentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount` etc) or need to keep its own state.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it sych a way:

```
/* your imports and other declarations stays the same*/
class Breadcrumb extends React.Component { 
  render(){
    return (<div className="breadcrumbComponent">
      {this.props.breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, index) => (
        <span key={breadcrumb.key}>
            <NavLink
                className = 'highlight'
                to = {breadcrumb.props.match.url}
            >
                {breadcrumb}
            </NavLink>

            {(index < breadcrumbs.length - 1) && <i> > </i>}
        </span>
        ))}
     </div>
  )
}

export default WithBreadcrumbs(routes)(BreadCrumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try this (untested)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import WithBreadcrumbs from 'react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc';
import './Breadcrumb.css';

const merchantBreadcrumb = ({ match }) => <span>{match.params.merchantName}</span>;
const routes = [
  { path: '/merchant/:merchantName', breadcrumb: merchantBreadcrumb }
]

export class WithBreadcrumbs extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    breadcrumbs: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  }
  render() {
    const { breadcrumbs } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="breadcrumbComponent">
        {
          breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, index) => (
            <span key={breadcrumb.key}>
              <NavLink
                className='highlight'
                to={breadcrumb.props.match.url}
              >
                {breadcrumb}
              </NavLink>
              {(index < breadcrumbs.length - 1) && <i> > </i>}
            </span>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default routes(WithBreadcrumbs);
```